# forEach required field only

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, foreach

I've been able to successfully perform a forEach over all select fields but I cant evaluate required selects only.  How can I adjust my js to apply only to the required fields?

```
<form>
<div>
<select required="true">
 <option value>- Select -</option>
 <option value>- option 1 -</option>
 <option value>- option 2 -</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<select required="true">
 <option value>- Select -</option>
 <option value>- sample 1 -</option>
 <option value>- sample 2 -</option>
</select>

</div>
<div><select>
 <option value>- Select -</option>
 <option value>- optional 1 -</option>
 <option value>- optional 2 -</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
let check_inputs = js_form.querySelectorAll("select :checked");

[].forEach.call(sel_inputs, function (elm) {
    if (!elm.value) {
      not_pass = true;
      elm.closest(".usa-form-group").classList.add(error_container_class);
    } else {
      elm.closest(".usa-form-group").classList.remove(error_container_class);
    }
  });
</script>
```

but my attempt is always true. How can I apply the class to only required fields within this forEach?

```
[].forEach.call(sel_inputs, function (elm) {
    if (!elm.value && !elm.hasAttribute("required")) {
      not_pass = true;
      elm.closest(".usa-form-group").classList.add(error_container_class);
    } else {
      elm.closest(".usa-form-group").classList.remove(error_container_class);
    }
  });
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("select[required]").forEach(function(elm){...});`

Comment: Why do `[].forEach.call` when you can select the select elements with required attribute using `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: And, by the way, `required` is a Boolean attribute, the mere presence of it makes the element required. You can set it to whatever you want and that won't change the fact that the element will be required. But if you do want to give it a value, it is customary to make the value the same as the attribute (i.e. `required="required"`).

Comment: `js_form.querySelectorAll("select[required] :checked");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document.querySelectorAll("select[required=true]")` as your element selector returns only `select` elements that have the `required` attribute set to `true`. This uses CSS selectors and more information about that can be found on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

```js
document.querySelectorAll("select[requred=true]").forEach(function(elem){
    // Function code here...
});
```